# PrimeVue theme change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

Apparently, in the last few PrimeVue updates there has been a `PrimeVue.changeTheme()` method that I would very much like to use. The documentation says that two things are required.

1. copying the selected themes from the PrimeVue `resources/themes` folder and placing them under the public folder.
2. In the `index.html` file, create links to these styles along with giving them an ID so that this ID is later passed to the function.

So that's what I did but the solution doesn't quite work, perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.
Link to docs: https://primevue.org/theming/

index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link id="lara-dark-purple-link" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/lara-dark- 
    purple/theme.css">
    <link id="lara-light-purple-link" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/lara-light- 
    purple/theme.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is code from component which hold buttons with theme changing:

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { usePrimeVue } from 'primevue/config';

const PrimeVue  = usePrimeVue();
const toggleDarkMode = () => {
  PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-dark-purple', 'lara-dark-purple', 'lara-dark-purple-link', () => {});    
}
const toggleLightMode = () => {
  PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-light-purple', 'lara-light-purple', 'lara-light-purple-link', () => {});
}
</script>
```

My folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. You just didn't understand the use of the `<link>` `id`, but no problem, let me quickly summarize it for you:

#### 1.) Need a new reference element to theme css file.

> Second part is making the theme.css accessible via a link element...

```html
<!-- Add default theme url to href | now default is light -->
<link id="id-to-link" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/lara-light-purple/theme.css">
```

#### 2.) Use `your-id` in function as 3rd parameter.

> ...so that the id of the link can be provided as the **3rd parameter** to the changeTheme function.

```js
// if current theme is dark
const selectLightTheme = () => {
    // 1. Current theme name
    // 2. Next theme name
    // 3. id of <link>, what reference to where set theme css file
    PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-dark-purple', 'lara-light-purple', 'id-to-link', () => {});    
}

// if current theme is light
const selectDarkTheme = () => {
    // 1. Current theme name
    // 2. Next theme name
    // 3. id of <link>, what reference to where set theme css file
    PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-light-purple', 'lara-dark-purple', 'id-to-link', () => {});
}
```

Source from documentation: https://primevue.org/theming/

### How to make dynamically?

```html
<!-- Add default theme url to href | now default is light -->
<link id="id-to-link" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/lara-light-purple/theme.css">
```

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { usePrimeVue } from 'primevue/config';

// set default theme folder-name to currentTheme
const currentTheme = ref('lara-light-purple'); // lara-light-purple or lara-dark-purple (1st parameter)

const PrimeVue = usePrimeVue();

// change current theme to next
const toggleTheme = () => {
    // What is next theme? (2nd parameter)
    let nextTheme = 'lara-light-purple';
    if (currentTheme.value === 'lara-light-purple') nextTheme = 'lara-dark-purple';
    else if (currentTheme.value === 'lara-dark-purple') nextTheme = 'lara-light-purple';

    // 1. Current theme name
    // 2. Next theme name
    // 3. id of <link>, what reference to where set theme css file --> fix, single id to <link>
    PrimeVue.changeTheme(currentTheme.value, nextTheme, 'id-to-link', () => {});    

    // So current theme now:
    currentTheme.value = nextTheme;
}
```

#### CDN Live Example

```js
// CDN Vue Import
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    // set default theme folder-name to currentTheme
    const currentTheme = ref('lara-light-purple'); // lara-light-purple or lara-dark-purple (1st parameter)

    // const PrimeVue = usePrimeVue(); // If I were not using CDN, my PrimeVue variable would not exist yet. In that case, I would need to declare it with the usePrimeVue() function loaded from primevue/config

    // change current theme to next
    const toggleTheme = () => {
      // What is next theme? (2nd parameter)
      let nextTheme = 'lara-light-purple';
      if (currentTheme.value === 'lara-light-purple') nextTheme = 'lara-dark-purple';
      else if (currentTheme.value === 'lara-dark-purple') nextTheme = 'lara-light-purple';

      // PrimeVue.changeTheme('lara-light-purple', 'lara-dark-purple', 'id-to-link', () => {});
      // --> The usePrimeVue() function is not available in the CDN version, so I am currently implementing a native JS solution in place of changeTheme (the only additional task is to ensure the FULL URL for both templates)
      // Native JS Solution:
      document.getElementById('id-to-link').href = `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/resources/themes/${nextTheme}/theme.css`

      // So current theme now:
      currentTheme.value = nextTheme;
    }

    return { toggleTheme }
  },
  components: {
    "Button": primevue.button,
  },
  template: `
    <Button label="Click to Toggle Theme" @click="toggleTheme" />
  `
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<!-- Core Vue -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.12/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<!-- Core Primevue -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.44.0/core/core.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add default theme url to href | now default is light -->
<link id="id-to-link" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primevue@3.32.2/resources/themes/lara-light-purple/theme.css">

<!-- App -->
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: So I as understand my solution should work but I missunderstanded how it should be done to be dynamically? Because the solution is not working for me (theme is not changing).

Comment: I indeed misunderstood the theme ID as the third parameter! I will modify my answer! However, please note that your solution is also incorrect, as the first and second parameters of `changeTheme()` cannot be the same! Now, I tested my dynamic function, and it works! Please read carefully the difference between your code and mine! The main difference is that the **first and second parameters** of `changeTheme()` are **not identical**, and the **third parameter always refers to a `<link>` element** whose href attribute is manipulated by PrimeVue.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! So I guess function changeTheme is overwriting the href value in <link> element. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a simple solution!

### index.html

```html
<link id="theme-link" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/aura-dark-teal/theme.css">
```

---

### Options API

```js
data() {
  return {
    currentTheme: 'aura-dark-teal',
    nextTheme: 'aura-light-blue',
  }
},

methods: {
  toggleTheme() {
    [this.currentTheme, this.nextTheme] = [this.nextTheme, this.currentTheme]
    this.$primevue.changeTheme(this.currentTheme, this.nextTheme, 'theme-link', () => {})
  }
}
```

---

### Composition API

```js
let currentTheme = 'aura-dark-teal'
let nextTheme = 'aura-light-blue'

const primeVue = usePrimeVue();

toggleTheme() {
    [this.currentTheme, this.nextTheme] = [this.nextTheme, this.currentTheme]
    primeVue.changeTheme(currentTheme.value, nextTheme, 'id-to-link', () => {});
```

---

And you can save the `currentTheme` and `nextTheme` in the browser's localStorage to preserve the users' theme selection between sessions.